# How do I enable call waiting notification when I am calling another person?

Tags: htc-desire-s, call-waiting

When I used my previous phone, when I am calling someone, I used to get a notification if the party that I am calling is in another call and I am waiting. I usually don't like to disturb people when they are in another call so I promptly hang up. But I've noticed that my **HTC Desire S** does not tell me that information.

Is it by design ?

Is there anyway I can enable this feature?

An app perhaps?

Or are all the phones running Android have this feature turned off ?

Just to clarify, I am **NOT** looking for activating call waiting on my phone so I get an alert when another person is calling me. I want to know when a call *I* initiated is in call-waiting on the other end.

Comment: It's maybe a provider feature on the side which get's called. I think that there is no setting for this in Android.

Comment: My HTC one s has the same issue with jelly bean. I've called HTC support and they answered that this is not a phone problem, but instead it's a software limitation, then, i asked that lady if HTC knows what's better for me, so i don't need to know if i disturb someone or not...
I am waiting for solving with real interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, most (maybe all) of the Android phones don't have this option. Check this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7048

Comment: All complaints seem to be by HTC and Motorola users. I've never bumped into this problem on Samsung phones (Galaxy 3/S/S2/Tab), so it's not all Android phones that suffer from this.

Answer (score 1):

The setting is under Dialer. Just click on the Dialer, got to `settings -> additional settings` and then select the check box opposite to Call Waiting option.

This option was changed in ICS update I believe.

Answer (score -2):

This problem does not exist in Samsung Mobile. I dont know much about HTC. You can consult to servie centre. May be there can be any setting issue.